# Creating Query Definition with SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, query-definition

I am trying to create Query Definition using SSJS but its not working for me.
my code as follows:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1");

var queryDef = {
    Name : "Example Query Definition",
    CustomerKey : "myQueryDef",
    TargetUpdateType : "Overwrite",
    TargetType : "DE", 
    Target:{
    Name:"errorlog",
    CustomerKey : "errorlogkey"
    },
QueryText : "SELECT SubKey, Email, Name FROM [target DE] where FavoriteItemID=77"
};

var status = QueryDefinition.Add(queryDef);
var outDE=DataExtension.Init("errorlog"); // just to see the result
outDE.Rows.Add({message:status});
</script>
```

when i run this script using automation studio it runs but didn't create any Query :(  also the status says 'ERROR' on the output..

please can some one help..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are able to add your query manually in Automation Studio based on the definitions that you wrote above, then the code needs to work.

I have created a data extension named "errorlog" with the customer key of "errorlogkey". It has one field named "num". Then, I wrote my query based on that information.

At the end, the code below worked:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1") ;

var queryDef = { Name : "Example Query Definition",

CustomerKey : "myQueryDef",
TargetUpdateType : "Overwrite",
TargetType : "DE",

Target:{
Name:"errorlog",
CustomerKey : "errorlogkey"
},
QueryText : "SELECT SubscriberKey as num FROM EOL_test2"
};

var status = QueryDefinition.Add(queryDef);

var outDE=DataExtension.Init("errorlog"); // just to see the result

 outDE.Rows.Add(  {message:status});

</script>
```

For detailed information: http://emailpeer.com/creating-an-sql-query-in-ssjs/

Comment: thanks buddy working good, i made a stupid thing.. i put the same DE name on the Target and Sql Select statement so the TargetUpdateType should be 'Update' rather then 'Overwrite'.. Thanks for spending your time..