# SSJS to create Import Defination in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I would like to create an Import Defination in marketing cloud using SSJS, where my  source should be one dataExtenion and the traget should be another dataextension. I also want to start the ImportDefinition from my script, but I can't find how to do it.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why create an import definition to get data from a DE to another ? You can achieve this using an SQL query inside of an Automation and either schedule your automation or fire it using an API call depending on your use case..

Comment: Yes, we can use SQL query for this. But in our scenario, for everyday deployment process, we are creating a copy of 15 new data extension and move the records from one data extension to another. So I thought like to automate this entire process. i am able create a copy of DE using SSJS but I am unable to find the Script  to copy the Records. So thought to write script for import definition and just change the source and target DE. If I go with SQL approach, I need to create 15 SQL activity, which is time consuming. @RachidMamai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, it sounds like the issue is not that you are tied to creating an import process, but that you want a way to fill in the 15 new DEs you create. I think your solution is to use queries, but you can create and perform these programatically via SSJS.

First thing I would make sure to save the names of the DEs you created inside of another DE for reference in the second script. I would then, as a second script, [create](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227206/creating-query-definition-with-ssjs) and [perform](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_queryDefinitionPerform.htm) query activities to fill in these data extensions. You will likely need to create a For loop based off the DE holding your newly created DE names to ensure you create and execute accordingly.

Simple example of the create then execute script for Query:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1") ;

var deName = {{yourTargetDEName}}

var queryName = {{yourQueryName}}

var queryDef = { Name : queryName,

CustomerKey : queryName,
TargetUpdateType : "Overwrite",
TargetType : "DE",

Target:{
Name: deName,
CustomerKey : deName
},
QueryText : "SELECT {{myField}} FROM {{mySourceDE}}"
};

var status = QueryDefinition.Add(queryDef);

sleep(3000); //Wait for 3 seconds
//This helps ensure creation is complete before attempting to execute

var qd = QueryDefinition.Init("myQueryDef");
var status = qd.Perform();


function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Now there are things to consider while doing this in that you will have 15 Queries targeting the same source DE, so you may run into issues there - but with some adjustments and customization, you can get this going to automate your process.